# new products list - with title & short description

Tags: magento-1.9, widgets, new-products

I want my New Products (list) widget to display the Title & Short Description of the items. E.g. www.pccasegear.com there "New products" section on there home page.

I've had a look at a few addons/extensions but none of them seem to do what I want. Is there a way I can edit this widget to display the Short Description on each product? Maybe even have a character limit.

At the moment I've just got

> {{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new"
>   display_type="all_products" products_count="10"
>   template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml"}}

EDIT2: Everything seems to be working (no error codes) with the below code. Except I keep getting "There are no products to display". I've tried setting today's date and future days with the same message. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: paste the code from the file catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in your file

```
app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourpackage/catalog/product/new.phtml


<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
/* @var $this Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List */
?>
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                <?php /* Based on the native RWD styling, product images are displayed at a max of ~400px wide when viewed on a
                        one column page layout with four product columns from a 1280px viewport. For bandwidth reasons,
                        we are going to serve a 300px image, as it will look fine at 400px and most of the times, the image
                        will be displayed at a smaller size (eg, if two column are being used or viewport is smaller than 1280px).
                        This $_imgSize value could even be decreased further, based on the page layout
                        (one column, two column, three column) and number of product columns. */ ?>
                <?php $_imgSize = 300; ?>
                <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                     src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                     alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
            </a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <div class="product-primary">
                        <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>                     
                    </div>                   
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <?php /*if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
            <?php endif*/ ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                    <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                         src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                         alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                </a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>                                        
                </div>
                <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php /*if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
            <?php endif*/ ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
// Provides a block where additional page components may be attached, primarily good for in-page JavaScript
if ($this->getChild('after')) {
    $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach ($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName) {
        $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
        //set product collection on after blocks
        $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
        echo $_afterChild->toHtml();
    }
}
?>
```

Add below code to when you want to ad in cms block or cms page:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Will try this when I get back to the office and let you know.

Comment: I'm getting errors. Edited my main question.

Comment: Updated answer please check it

Comment: The page now opens with no errors, but it now says "There are no products matching the selection".

Comment: You can view the page @ http://www.zyqor.com.au/

Comment: you need to set product date from product edit page so you can see product as new product on home page

Comment: Still saying, "There are no products matching the selection". My set New to Date and Set Date, I've tried todays date for both and a future date, it's displaying the same message. I've also tried refreshing/relaoding cache in Magento & Browser with same message.

Comment: I had to add
$productList_block  = Mage::app()->getLayout()
                     ->createBlock('catalog/product_list'); 

To the top of
$_productCollection=$productList_block->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');